# Is there a way to find the a value in a excel table with two or more informations?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I don't know how to explain this better, but I extract a report in xls format, that record the offer from companys during a bid. The report contains three fields:

Value / Company / Time

I want to extract the first offer from a company, but I'm facing the following problem:
The report don't consider days just time, so if a company send me an offer in 2019-01-28 at 10 PM and after this send me another offer in 2019-01-29 at 09 PM, in my report will appear the second offer first.

I've been doing this manually cuz it's impossible to use vlookup in this case.

I tried with VBA too, something like this To define the  range where the data is:

```
    tableRowi = tableI.Row  'Linha de início da Tabela de Lances
    Set tableF = Range("A1:Z1000").Find(What:="Relatório de Chat do Leilão", LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    Set tableF2 = Range("A1:Z1000").Find(What:="Usuários Conectados ao Monitor do Leilão", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If tableF Is Nothing Then
        tableRowF = tableF2.Row
    Else
        tableRowF = tableF.Row
    End If
```

and this to copy the  data that i want:

```
 Set propI = Range("A" & tableRowi - 2 & ":Z1000").Find(What:="Valor", LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False) 'Início da tabela de classificação
    propCol = propI.Column 'Coluna com valores das propostas
    Set empI = Range("A" & tableRowi - 2 & ":Z1000").Find(What:="Empresa", LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False) 'Início da tabela de classificação
    empCol = empI.Column 'Coluna com nomes das empresas que deram lances

    'Copiando os dados
    Dim arrayLance() As Variant
    ReDim arrayLance(0 To nEmpresas - 1) 'Propostas iniciais
    For i = 0 To nEmpresas - 1
        'Set Emp = Range("A1:Z1000").Find(What:=arrayEmp(i), LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False) 'Início da tabela de classificação
        arrayLance(i) = WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("A1:Z1000"), tableRowi - 1 + WorksheetFunction.Match(arrayEmp(i), Range(Cells(tableRowi, empCol), Cells(tableRowF, empCol)), 0), propCol)
    Next i
```

In this code I set the columns where the data is and copy them using arrays, but again I face the same problem, the code pickup the first information (value) from an Company which s is not necessarily your first offer.

I thought to use a loop but i cant structure this in my mind.

Comment: Without the dates how would you do this manually?

Comment: Please note that SO is not a free code writing service. What does your data look like? what is the expected result? what have you tried so far? How does it fail to meet expectations? Plesae [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59956884/edit) to provide this information

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad thanks for the feedback, i updated my question.